# WEB FORM template 2012 + Toolbox + Bootstrap 3 How to use together?

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use .Net web form template in VS2012 and the toolbox together with boostrap 3?

- WEB FORM template
- Toolbox (drag and drop control provided by VS)
- Bootstrap 3

I hope to find a way to use them together. Anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by "toolbox"?

Comment: The drag and drop control provided by VS.